# Prevent white flash between page loads electron

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, electron

Each time the window starts to loads new html or makes a makes request to the server the Window will go white until the page has finished loading or server has responded to the request. This does not look good at all and can be quite jarring.
How can I stop this?

The code if you wish to see it 
 app.js

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');
let win;
function createWindow () {
    // Create the browser window.
    win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});
    win.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    }));

    win.on('closed', () => {
        win = null;
})
}
app.on('ready', createWindow);
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {

    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
}
});

app.on('activate', () => {

    if (win === null) {
    createWindow()
}
});
```

inedx.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body style="background-color: #222222">
<a href="index.html" style="color: white">Click on me to see a flash</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9):

As far as I have seen (like here: [4 must-know tips for building cross platform Electron apps](https://blog.avocode.com/blog/4-must-know-tips-for-building-cross-platform-electron-apps)) setting the background color of the window is the typical way to at least mitigate the "flash". Perhaps you could get fancy with a `CSS` transition to fade out the window content before loading and then fade it in once the new content has loaded?

From that site:

> 2.1 Specify a BrowserWindow background color If your application has a non-white background color, make sure to specify it in your
>   BrowserWindow options. This won't prevent the square-of-solid-color
>   while your application loads, but at least it doesn't also change
>   color halfway through:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    title: 'ElectronApp',
    backgroundColor: '#002b36',
  };
```

> 2.2 Hide your application until your page has loaded: Because we're actually in the browser, we can choose to hide the windows until we
>   know all our resources have been loaded in. Upon starting, make sure
>   to hide your browser window:

```
var mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      title: 'ElectronApp',
      show: false,
  };
```

> Then, when everything is loaded, show the window and focus it so it
>   pops up for the user. You can do this with the "ready-to-show" event
>   on your `BrowserWindow`, which is recommended, or the
>   'did-finish-load' event on your webContents.

```
mainWindow.on('ready-to-show', function() {
      mainWindow.show();
      mainWindow.focus();
  });
```

Comment: unfortunately this has not fixed problem the background color only affects the app when it starts and the other changes have no noticeable effect.I cannot understand why electron does this as no other web browser behaves in this way.

Comment: I might just have to use a single page application

Comment: I face the same issue

Comment: @Ashlin – looks like some experimentation is in order! I'd first check to see if an issue has been filed for this at the Electron github site and what, if any, discussion there is about it. Then maybe get clever – maybe have two windows stacked like cards: load in the hidden one and only show it "on ready" etc.

Answer (score 0):

What helps me to mitigate this issue the most, is to set the window height to 1, and then restore it to the original value, like so:

```js
const createWindow = () => {
   const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 1200,
      height: 1,
      webPreferences: {
         preload: path.join(__dirname, './js/preload.js')
      }
   });

   mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
      mainWindow.setSize(1200, 800);
    });
```

this way only the window system menu goes white when the window first appears.